# Svelte: else if block condition not evaluated after if block condition changes

Tags: javascript, svelte

Edit: it is a bug https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/7043

Considering [the following example](https://svelte.dev/repl/d78be03ee17d40c7a67afd3c0a7fa330?version=3.44.3) one would expect 'bar' to be rendered under the second horizontal rule whenever `foo` is `false` and `bar[0]` is `true`.

```js
<script>
    let foo = true
    let bar = [false];
</script>

<button on:click={() => foo = !foo}>
    Toggle foo
</button>
<button on:click={() => bar[0] = !bar[0]}>
    Toggle bar
</button>

<hr>
{@html `foo: ${foo}, bar: ${bar.every(x => x)}`}
<hr>

{#if foo}
    foo!
{:else if bar.every(x => x)}
    bar!
{/if}
```

However, if the following steps are executed, the reactivity seemingly breaks:

1. Set `foo` to `true`
2. Set `bar[0]` to `true`
3. Set `foo` to `false`

Nothing is rendered under the horizontal rule even though the `else if` block condition is satisfied. This is not the case if the else if condition is simply `bar[0]`, so it seems like using a function is the cause for it not being evaluated. Similar behavior when `bar` is `true` before `foo` is toggled and `false` after `foo` is toggled again, unexpectedly 'bar' is rendered at the bottom.

The same effect can be observed when `foo` is switched between `null` and `[]` with the `else if` condition being `Array.isArray(bar)`.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: I share your feeling that this behaviour is unexpected and wonder too why the `else if` doesn't seem to be reeveluated when the opening `#if` condition changes. I can't tell if/why there's a difference between a method call like `bar.every(x => x)` and the pointer to a value like `bar[0]`, but my solution would be to use a `reactive statement` for the method call `$: condition = bar.every(x => x)` and use the variable down below `{:else if condition}` which seems to work as expected [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5a54dc4c382c4a9a8338519e0ab2887f?version=3.44.3)

Comment: Thanks, that is a pretty good workaround! Still, I'm wondering whether this is desired behavior...

Comment: Turns out this is a bug! Tan Li Hau opened a PR to fix it: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/7043

Comment: Oh thats pretty cool :) thanks for the info

Comment: Looks like that issue with reactivity was fixed in mentioned PR and code works.

Answer (score 0):

Its not really a bug, its kinda expected behaviour in your scenario, when you changed `foo to true` then `bar to true` now bar is set and when changed `foo to false` again `bar didn't change` if you think about it to trigger reactivity!

the fix for that is to trigger it yourself once any of the values changes:

```
{#key foo || bar}
    {#if foo}
        foo!
    {:else if bar.every(x => x)}
        bar!
    {/if}
{/key}
```

Here is a working [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/cf252d181c514a309044468c8b734c90?version=3.44.3)

Comment: Huh, thanks for your answer. Well I kind of expected the else if statement to be reevaluated whenever the if statement changes, as is the case when the else if condition is `bar[0]`: https://svelte.dev/repl/429d30493b544231a305f0ea9805f282 here the above steps do not produce the same result. It is weird that some conditions are reevaluated while some are not, really feels like a bug tbh.

Comment: @cornzz it is working! `svelte.dev/repl/cf252d181c514a309044468c8b734c90`

Comment: Yes your example is indeed working, I was still referring to my initial example.